# 'uses' statement to access multiple repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a pipeline for dependency management tool [Renovate](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/azure/):

```yaml
# Runs the renovate bot on a schedule.
# Adapted from: https://blog.objektkultur.de/how-to-setup-renovate-in-azure-devops/

schedules:
  - cron: "0 5 * * *"
    displayName: "Every day at 7am"
    branches:
      include:
        - main
        - master
    always: true

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - group: "renovatebot"

steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
    fetchDepth: 1
    
  - bash: |
      git config --global user.email 'bot@renovateapp.com'
      git config --global user.name 'Renovate Bot'
      echo "TOKEN = $TOKEN"
      echo "GITHUB_COM_TOKEN = $GITHUB_COM_TOKEN"
      npx renovate
    env:
      TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      GITHUB_COM_TOKEN: $(githubtoken) # get a token from https://github.com/settings/tokens and save it in the 'renovatebot' variables group
      #RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE: "./pipelines/renovate/config.js" # use this environment variable if you prefer to have the renovate pipeline definition and the config file in it's own dictionary instead of the repository root.
```

It uses the `System.AccessToken` to run GIT commands.
This works for a single repo, but i'm trying to incorporate another repository into the same pipeline - i'm getting the following error however:

`ERROR: Repository is not found (repository=[REDACTED]/[REDACTED])`

This leads me to believe there is some auth issues accessing the second repository.

Reading through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#protect-access-to-repositories-in-yaml-pipelines
Then leads me to the 'uses' statement:

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: git://FabrikamFiber/FabrikamTools # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
- script: # Do something with that repo
# Or you can reference it with a uses statement in the job
uses:
  repositories: # List of referenced repositories
  - FabrikamTools # Repository reference to FabrikamTools
steps:
- script: # Do something with that repo like clone it
```

However, if i try that in azure, i'm getting an error:

[image]

What am i missing? what is the correct usage of the 'uses' statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the correct usage of the 'uses' statement?

To use the **uses:** statement, you need to define it at job level.

For example:

```
jobs:
  - job: test
    uses:
     repositories:
       - test
    steps:
      - script:xxx
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [jobs.job definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines)